# I am not quite sure what is math.ceiling doing here

Tags: c#, function, math

Can somebody please tell me what is math.ceiling function doing here because I think Math.Pow will do the job without it? You don't need the rest of the code to understand because the code would do the same without Math.Ceiling. I just need information whether Math.Ceiling makes sure that Math.Pow has really calculated its number in the right way or does it mean something else. Thanks in advance

```
a[i] = a[i-1] * 10 + 45 * (int)(Math.Ceiling(Math.Pow(10, i-1)));
```

Comment: I assume that `i` is a positive integer? If so, there's no point to this.

Comment: Ooh this is nasty...Math.Ceiling is useless here. Cast to (int) is needed if your array is of type int.

Comment: @sidprasher The `Math.Ceiling` call is unnecessary either case - it couldn't possibly do anything, or this line would either throw an exception or not even compile.

Comment: It is a hacky workaround for floating point accuracy problems, Math.Pow() may return a value like 999.9999.. instead of 1000.  A cast would produce 999.  For values that can be cast to (int) that is a sign of the processor control word being set wrong by a library.

Answer (score 3):

The call is completely pointless. Since `i` is an index into the array, it must be a positive integer - otherwise, this will either crash (if `i` is 0 or less) due to not being a valid index into the array or not even compile in the first place (if `i` is not an integer at all). That being said, `Math.pow` is already guaranteed to return an integer in this case, so it will never make any difference in the output.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you!

Comment: @MatejaZatezalo Glad I could help. If this answered the question, can you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 0):

`Math.ceiling()` is the guarantee that your number will be an integer, like, if the pow returns a float number, Math.ceiling will round up the number.
Ex.: Pow returns 2.7, Math.ceiling returns 3.

Assuming that `i` is already an integer, there is no real need for the `Math.ceiling()` function, because the `pow` return will always be an integer.

Hope that is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: That's technically true, but `i` appears to already be an integer, in which case the call to `Math.Ceiling` would be pointless.

Comment: what if `i` is `-1`? 10 to the power of -2 is 0.01

Comment: If `i` is -1, this'll crash anyway because it's not a valid index into the array. `i` must be a positive integer.

Comment: true, I didn't pay much attention to the left end it seems.

Comment: In that case there is no need for the Math.ceiling() function.

Comment: The only case where it would make any difference is if `i` is 0 or less (in which case there will be an exception) or if `i` is a floating-point number of some kind (in which case this won't even compile because array indices must be integers). So yes, the call is pointless.

Comment: Thank you very much guys